# SQL Error 3183 on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, restore, dbcc-checkdb

I have a backup of database version SQL Server 2008 R2. While restoring it to SQL Server 2012 I am getting error:

> msg 3183 **RESTORE detected an error on page (6100:1886858449) in database ...** .

While restoring the same file on another instance of 2008 R2, it is being restored successfully.

I performed DBCC CHECKDB(DB NAME) and then taken the manual backup and using this backup file, I restored the file. It got restored successfully.

Why does this happen? Am I right while doing this or is something missing?

Comment: Any chance that you are trying to restore the backup from a n/w share ? Also, best is to use **CHECKSUM** when you take backups. Seems problem with the hardware - Disk ?

Comment: Verify good functioning of the storage subsystem.